# MS Graph (Outlook) List messages 'ReceivedDateTime GT' operation failing by 1 second

Tags: datetime, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-mail

The MS Graph (Outlook) List messages 'ReceivedDateTime GT' operator is failing by 1 second !

If you add 1 second to the desired 'ReceivedDateTime', you get emails with precisely that 'ReceivedDateTime' OR Greater.

If you specify the exact 'ReceivedDateTime' that you would only like to List mails 'Greater Than', it also returns mails with the very same -- 'EQ' -- 'ReceivedDateTime'.

Please fix this GT operator MS, as you can imagine how much chaos it is causing today.

Regards, Cameron

I tried:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<email_address>/messages$filter=ReceivedDateTime GT 2024-01-01T01:01:01Z

I got:
emails with 'ReceivedDateTime' EQUAL to 2024-01-01T01:01:01Z (AND Greater)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook evaluates time according to that specified time format without seconds.

Both the Outlook UI and Outlook Object Model share the same code that forces truncation to the nearest minute, there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if I add a single second it works perfectly and exactly as expected ?